# CMakeLists and Clang sanitization options for an ncurses program

Tags: c, cmake

I would like some feedback on a CMakeLists.txt file I created for compiling my project. I have pasted the CMakeLists as well as my source code below. One thing I would specifically appreciate feedback on the sanitization options I have enabled. Are there more I should enable, and/or should I should reduce? I know `-fsanitize=address, -fsanitize=thread, and -fsanitize=memory` groups can't be used with others (according to the clang documentation). Would one of the other groups be better preferred to use on a first-pass rather than the one I chose (`address`)?

Also - the blob feature I am using, I have based on a StackOverflow answer I read - I understand that this doesn't detect new C source files and I'm fine with that, but besides that subtle detail is this an okay practice to follow?

**CMakeLists.txt**

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.13)
project(FirstProject C)

find_package(Curses REQUIRED)
include_directories(${CURSES_INCLUDE_DIR})

set(CMAKE_C_COMPILER clang)
set(CMAKE_C_STANDARD 99)
set (CMAKE_C_FLAGS "${CMAKE_C_FLAGS} -Weverything -fsanitize=undefined,integer,implicit-conversion,nullability,address,leak,cfi -flto -fvisibility=default")

FILE(GLOB Sources *.c)
add_executable(${CMAKE_PROJECT_NAME} ${Sources})
target_link_libraries(${CMAKE_PROJECT_NAME} ${CURSES_LIBRARIES})
```

**main.c** (Code comes from [here](/a/210304/9357))

> ```
> #include <ctype.h>
> #include <errno.h>
> #include <inttypes.h>
> #include <limits.h>
> #include <ncurses.h>
> #include <stdint.h>
> #include <stdlib.h>
> #include <string.h>
>
> // Generous estimate of the maximum number of digits
> // https://stackoverflow.com/a/10536254
> #define ULL_DIGITS (3 * sizeof(unsigned long long))
> #define ERR_MSG_MAX_LENGTH 32
> #define NUL '\0'
> #define NUL_SIZE 1
>
> int ask_ull(unsigned long long *result, const char *prompt);
>
> /**
>  * Prints a prompt then reads an unsigned long long, using ncurses.
>
>  * Returns 0 on success.  Returns errno on failure, which is set to
>
>  * ERANGE, EDOM, or EIO.
>  */
> int ask_ull(unsigned long long *result, const char *prompt) {
>     char buf[ULL_DIGITS + NUL_SIZE];
>     char *endptr;
>     printw("%s", prompt);
>     getnstr(buf, ULL_DIGITS);
>     *result = strtoull(buf, &endptr, 10);
>     if (errno == ERANGE) {
>         // Overflow or underflow
>         return errno;
>     }
>     if (endptr == buf || strchr(buf, '-')) {
>         // Unsuccessful conversion
>         errno = EDOM;
>         return errno;
>     }
>     while (isspace(*endptr)) endptr++;
>     if (*endptr) {
>         // Trailing junk
>         errno = EIO;
>         return errno;
>     }
>     errno = 0;
>     return errno;
> }
>
> int main(void) {
>     unsigned long long height, width, length;
>     height = width = length = 0;
>
>     char errmsg[ERR_MSG_MAX_LENGTH];
>     errmsg[0] = NUL;
>
>     initscr();
>     printw("--- Volume Calculator --\n");
>     if (!ask_ull(&length, "Enter length: ")) {
>         sscanf(errmsg, "%s", "Unable to scan length");
>     }
>     if (!ask_ull(&width, "Enter width: ")) {
>         sscanf(errmsg, "%s", "Unable to scan width");
>     }
>     if (!ask_ull(&height, "Enter height: ")) {
>         sscanf(errmsg, "%s", "Unable to scan height");
>     }
>
>     if (errmsg[0] != NUL) {
>         refresh();
>         endwin();
>         perror(errmsg);
>         return errno;
>     }
>
>     unsigned long long volume = length * width * height;
>     printw("Volume: %llu", volume);
>     refresh();
>     getch();
>     endwin();
> }
> ```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not familiar with the Clang sanitization command-line options so I can't give any feedback about those,
but regarding the CMake code I would suggest the following *CMakeLists.txt* file

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.13)
project(FirstProject C)

find_package(Curses REQUIRED)

add_executable(${CMAKE_PROJECT_NAME} main.c)

target_include_directories(${CMAKE_PROJECT_NAME} PRIVATE ${CURSES_INCLUDE_DIR})
target_link_libraries(${CMAKE_PROJECT_NAME} PRIVATE ${CURSES_LIBRARIES})

if(NOT CMAKE_C_COMPILER_ID STREQUAL "Clang")
  message(WARNING "Use the Clang compiler instead. "
                  "FirstProject officially supports Clang "
                  "(although other compilers might work).") 
endif()       

target_compile_features(${CMAKE_PROJECT_NAME} PRIVATE c_std_99)
target_compile_options(${CMAKE_PROJECT_NAME} PRIVATE
  $<$<C_COMPILER_ID:Clang>:
    -Weverything
    -fsanitize=undefined,integer,implicit-conversion,nullability,address,leak,cfi
    -flto
    -fvisibility=default>)
target_link_options(${CMAKE_PROJECT_NAME} PRIVATE
  $<$<C_COMPILER_ID:Clang>:
    -fsanitize=undefined,integer,implicit-conversion,nullability,address,leak,cfi
    -flto>)
```

## Some comments

### Avoid using FILE(GLOB) to specify source code files

Avoid using [`FILE(GLOB)`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/file.html?highlight=file), instead specify the source code files explicitly either by

```
add_executable(${CMAKE_PROJECT_NAME} main.c)
```

or

```
add_executable(${CMAKE_PROJECT_NAME})
target_sources(${CMAKE_PROJECT_NAME} PRIVATE main.c)
```

Śee also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32411963/why-is-cmake-file-glob-evil

### Use target_* commands

Avoid

- using [`include_directories()`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/include_directories.html?highlight=include_directories#command:include_directories)
- setting [`CMAKE_C_FLAGS`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/envvar/CFLAGS.html?highlight=cmake_c_flags) directly

Instead use

- [`target_compile_features()`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/target_compile_features.html?highlight=target_compile_features#command:target_compile_features)
- [`target_compile_options()`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/target_compile_options.html?highlight=target_compile_options#command:target_compile_options)
- [`target_include_directories()`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/target_include_directories.html?highlight=target_include_directories#command:target_include_directories)
- [`target_link_libraries()`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/target_link_libraries.html?highlight=target_link_libraries#command:target_link_libraries)
- [`target_link_options()`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/target_link_options.html?highlight=target_link_options#command:target_link_options)

The [FindCurses](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/module/FindCurses.html?highlight=ncurses) module does not yet support imported targets as of today (2 January 2019, CMake 3.13.2) so it needs to 
be used in the old style

```
target_include_directories(${CMAKE_PROJECT_NAME} PRIVATE ${CURSES_INCLUDE_DIR})
target_link_libraries(${CMAKE_PROJECT_NAME} PRIVATE ${CURSES_LIBRARIES})
```

In the future (when support has been added to CMake for imported targets in FindCurses) the two lines should be replaced by the line:

```
target_link_libraries(${CMAKE_PROJECT_NAME} PRIVATE Curses::Curses)
```

Instead of setting the CMake variable [`CMAKE_C_STANDARD`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/variable/CMAKE_C_STANDARD.html?highlight=cmake_c_standard)

```
set(CMAKE_C_STANDARD 99)
```

is good practice to use  [`target_compile_features()`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/target_compile_features.html?highlight=target_compile_features#command:target_compile_features) instead

```
 target_compile_features(${CMAKE_PROJECT_NAME} PRIVATE c_std_99)
```

In this very case it makes no practical difference  but for a
 C++ header-only library, such compile features could be specified in the INTERFACE

```
 add_library(myheaderonly INTERFACE)
 target_compile_features(headeronlylib INTERFACE cxx_std_11)
```

to provide usage requirements for consumers of the library (see also https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/manual/cmake-buildsystem.7.html)

The `target_link_options()` line was added to be able to build the executable. (I am not sure it is correct).

### Use generator expressions

The [generator expression](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/manual/cmake-generator-expressions.7.html)

```
$<$<C_COMPILER_ID:Clang>:-Weverything -fsanitize=undefined,integer,implicit-conversion,nullability,address,leak,cfi -flto -fvisibility=default>
```

is expanded to

```
-Weverything -fsanitize=undefined,integer,implicit-conversion,nullability,address,leak,cfi -flto -fvisibility=default
```

when the Clang compiler is used, but for other compilers it is expanded to nothing.

### Avoid setting CMAKE_C_COMPILER

Instead of setting the CMake variable `CMAKE_C_COMPILER`, give a `WARNING` or a `FATAL_ERROR` whenever a  non-supported C compiler is used.

```
if(NOT CMAKE_C_COMPILER_ID STREQUAL "Clang")
  message(WARNING "Use the Clang compiler instead. FirstProject officially supports Clang (although other compilers might work).") 
endif()
```

(`WARNING` could be replaced by `FATAL_ERROR` to prevent the use of any other C compiler than Clang)

To compile the project, specify the C compiler with the environment variable [`CC`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/envvar/CC.html?highlight=cmake_c_compiler)

```
mkdir /tmp/build
cd /tmp/build
CC=clang cmake -G Ninja ~/FirstProject
ninja -v
```

Use the [ninja](https://ninja-build.org/) command-line flag `-v`  if you want to see the actual commands being run.

Comment: I appreciate the thorough answer. The last segment though, any particular advantage of using ninja over traditional make? Will it make a difference in compile-time speed?

Comment: Probably very little. For me the main advantages of `ninja` is that you don't need to specify the number of threads (e.g. make -j) and that the software is available for Linux, Mac and Windows.